# Openrowset passing file name as parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

For importing excel data into SQL Server am making use of OPENROWSET. This process in my application is very critical and would be used very often. Each upload there would be averagely 40K rows in the excel.

**Table Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].SampleTable(
    Sno [int] Primary key IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Col1] [varchar] (20) NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar] (30) NOT NULL,
    [Col3] [varchar] (30) NOT NULL
)
```

**Script using OPENROWSET to import xlsx data:**

```
    BEGIN TRAN
        BEGIN TRY

            --Import the xls data into a temp table
            SELECT * INTO #tmp 
            FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;
Database=E:\test.xlsx', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');

            --Remove existing data which matches the Col1 in the xls.
            DELETE FROM dbo.SampleTable 
            WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT  DISTINCT (Col1) FROM #tmp)

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable] (Col1, Col2, Col3)      
            SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM #tmp xls   

            --Clean up
            DROP TABLE #tmp;

        COMMIT TRAN

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
          ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH
```

Questions for which I am looking for help:

1. Want to convert this as a Stored Procedure which would take filename as a parameter. So that from my ASP.NET mvc page I can trigger this SP by passing just the filename.
2. Currently, on any error nothing gets imported. Is it possible to import all clean data and log erroneous data into a table / BCP out as a flat file etc.,?

Comment: You need to use DYNAMIC SQL to add an parameter to your ` OPENRTOWSET`